# Mathematical Games suitable for undergraduates

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics, big-list

I am looking for mathematical games for an undergraduate `maths club' for interested students. I am thinking of things like [topological tic-tac-toe](http://concretenonsense.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/topological-tic-tac-toe-1-the-torus/) and [singularity chess](http://abstractstrategygames.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/singularity-chess.html). I have some funding for this so it would be nice if some of these games were available to purchase, although I am open to making the equipment myself if necessary.

So the question is: what are some more examples of games that should be of interest to undergraduates in maths?

Comment: Maybe some of these http://www.brainbashers.com/logicpuzzles.asp

Answer (score 3):

I like Nim, and Dots and Boxes (which has an entire book written about it by Berlekamp).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Hex/Nash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29)? I've seen some quite elaborate boards, although they are often (always?) hand-crafted. The link to math would be Nash's non-constructive proof, Nash's life and work, and maybe analysis of connection games in general.

Comment: Note that my "board" consists of a bunch of hex nuts (enough for the desired board size) and white/black marbles, all in a bag.

Answer (score 2):

[Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28game%29) is a favourite of mine - it's really easy to pick up, and is great for the logical people.

Answer (score 1):

[Ticket to Ride](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/9209/ticket-to-ride) is a very easy game to learn and can lead to some interesting discussions of graph theory. On a more bitter note, a game of [Settlers of Catan](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13/the-settlers-of-catan) never fails to provide a wonderful example of the difference between theoretical and empirical probability.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few mathematical/logical games that the WFF 'N Proof people have out there.  I won't link to Equations, because I think that game least likely to come as interesting for undergraduates (but maybe I'm wrong).

I've only played [WFF 'N Proof](http://gamesforthinkers.pinnaclecart.com/logic/wff-n-proof-the-game-of-modern-logic/).   But, I will say that it teaches you propositional calculus and helps you to construct your own logical systems.

They have a game called [On Sets](http://gamesforthinkers.pinnaclecart.com/math/on-sets-the-game-of-set-theory/) which helps you learn set theory.

A [Real Numbers](http://gamesforthinkers.pinnaclecart.com/math/real-numbers/) game... which I don't think teaches you about Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts, but probably still has value to it.

A game called [Configurations](http://gamesforthinkers.pinnaclecart.com/math/configurations-number-puzzles-for-all-ages/) which has a sequence of geometric puzzles based on a book about Projective Geometry called The Geometry of Incidence which you can find on their website or on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CMY9J) or possibly in your library.

They also have a solitaire topological game/puzzle called [QWIK-SANE](http://gamesforthinkers.pinnaclecart.com/puzzles/qwik-sane-an-intriguing-topological-puzzle/).

Answer (score 0):

Group [twenty questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Questions). Depending on the allowable class of groups the difficulty can be scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Ergo is essentially "propositional logic: the card game", and isn't terribly fun if everyone's played before, but it's cute and mathematical.

The rules are at http://catalystgamelabs.com/pdfs/Ergo_Rules_LO.pdf