# What are the most fun and helpful math games?

Tags: card-games

I am looking for fun and helpful math games to play in my free time.

Most math games resort too much to calculation and are not actually helpful in other areas of intelligence - such as logical thinking, defining, relating etc.

Any recommendations?

Comment: This may be off-topic, but John Conway´s Game of Life is pretty interesting and pretty deep to analyze

Comment: @I.Padilla I had concerned with its off-topicness. If the majority evaluates it as off-topic, will delete the OP.

Comment: You'd have to give us a sense of what level of math you want to discuss

Comment: @ThomasAndrews at least undergraduate level of mathematics

Comment: May I suggest [Kal'toh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_in_Star_Trek#Kal-toh). Seriously now, an example of what you'd consider a fun and/or useful `math game` would help, even if it's not `the most` of either.

Comment: @dxiv Startrekers..

Comment: @Daschin I don't think this site is supposed to be for discussion, maybe you can try other sites such as Quora?

Comment: I guess math itself is the most challenging of math games

Comment: @Daschin See maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462723/mathematical-games-suitable-for-undergraduates) and [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13638/which-popular-games-are-the-most-mathematical) for some pointers.